# VS Code metals extension "New Scala project" button does not work

Tags: scala, scala-metals

#Hi all, i am new to scala, please don't judge.

The metals extension does not start a new scala project nor does it start metals if i do click the button below it.I have opened a folder "Temp" on the desktop and it is empty, it has no other files or folders in it, i do have sbt, respectively jdk 17 installed.[Recording Here](https://youtu.be/_0d1j9EGBmM)

Comment: This should be reported on issues/discussions on [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/scalameta/metals-vscode). We have no way of fixing it while authors do.